# SmartFoxServer Basic exitCurrentRoom = false not working

Tags: actionscript-3, smartfoxserver

I'm trying to stay in current room, but exitCurrentRoom = false is not working, I leave the room everytime, how can I fix this or what is the problem ?!

I want to keep every user in lobby room so they can receive updates until the game begins.

```
var gameRoom = {};
        gameRoom.name = user;
        gameRoom.password = "";
        gameRoom.maxUsers = 4;
        gameRoom.isGame = true;
        gameRoom.exitCurrentRoom = false;
```

sfs.createRoom(gameRoom);

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that **exitCurrentRoom** is **exitCurrent** actualy. Just wasted many hours on this, I hope it helps somebody.

More info [here](http://smartfoxserver.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=3348) on last post.